# The best way to create object hierarchy for inventory prototype

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, class-hierarchy

## 1. Item database

I am making inventory with c#. Usually i write programs with python and that's why i have some design problems with statically typed c#. Because of lack of practise.

I've created simple Item database. I have a general class `Item`. It has general properties like `id`, 'name'...
And to make new types of objects I inherit from `Item` class. For example `Weapon` item. Here is the code

Item.cs

```
public class Item {
  public string id;
  public string name;
  public string prefab;
  public string icon;

  public virtual string getTooltipText() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Weapon.cs

```
public class Weapon : Item {
  public int damage;

  public override string getTooltipText() {
    return "damage: " + damage;
  }
}
```

As you can see every time i need to create new type of object, i need to create new class inherited for `Item`

All items I load to dictionary and it works awesome

```
public Dictionary<string, Item> Items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
```

And create item class in terms of item type from database file

## 2. Question Part. Inventory

Right now I want to create an inventory using my Item database from the first part of this question. All items have general properties in user inventory. For example - *quantity* and ref to *item* from Item database. But main problem is that many items have their own unique stats. For example *durability*, *speed*, *quality* etc.

#### How can I design inventory item?

#### First idea

First idea (and it is ugly) is to create BIG class with all stats for all types of objects

```
public class InventoryItem {
  //main properties
  public Item item;
  public int quantity;

  //all properties for all other items
  public int durability;
  public int speed;
  public string quality;
  public string magic;
  ...
}
```

And I have to fill with *zero* and *null* all unused properties in terms of Item type. 
It is ugly and i don't like this way of making *InventoryItem* class

#### Second idea

Like in my Item database I can create separate class for every inventory item type: *InventoryWeapon*, *InventoryPlant*, *InventorySpells* etc.

And it looks better than BIG BOSS SINGLE *InventoryItem* class.

But I have feeling that I am doing something wrong. I am making double work. Every time i need to create new type of object, I have to create new  *Item* in item database (for example `public class Plant : Item`) and i have to create new *InventoryItem* (for example `public class InventoryPlant : InventoryItem`)

My question is: The best way to create object hierarchy for inventory prototype?

The best design?

Or maybe what I am doing wrong?

Or my idea with class for every type is right way of doing inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "best" design may not be achievable.  All you can do is design something that *works* and try to make it *better*.

When determining if composition or inheritance is appropriate think in terms if *is a* and *has a*.  *Is an* `InventoryItem` an item?  Or does it *have an* item?

If you design each type of item independent of each other, do they share common properties that can be facilitated by a base class?  Does that make `InventoryItem` more generic so you don't need `InventoryWeapon`, etc.?

> I am making double work.

How is a `InventoryWeapon` different than an `InventoryItem`?  Is it just because it contains a different type of item? Or are there properties and method specific to that type?  Can you use generics (e.g. `InventoryItem<TItem>`) to improve strong typing and code reuse? Yes, you may end up with coupled classes like `InventoryWeapon`, but if it's a better design than the alternative it's probably worth the extra effort.

These kinds of questions can only be answered by sketching out a design, seeing what works and what doesn't, and trying different things.  You're not going to get it right the first time, so the choice then is to plow through with what you have or step back and do something different.